# how to access list/dataframe values in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df with values below

```
> df
      X6 X7
    1  5  3
    2  1  4
    3  8  8
```

I want to access the first column and than the second colum in

```
my_vector2 <- sapply(data_train[df,5], function(x) x)
```

how can I do that? 
If anyone knows how to pass values of list in dataframe like explained above that would work as well

```
 >df
    $`6`
    [1] "5" "1" "8"

    $`7`
    [1] "3" "4" "8"
```

I want data_train to take the values 5,1,8 one by one and return the column value (5 is the fixed value) in the vector
5:5 = setosa 
5:1 = virsicolor

```
$`2`
[1] versicolor versicolor virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

$`8`
[1] virginica  setosa     versicolor
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

for example in $2 I'm getting versicolor two times so my variable "result" should get the answer versicolor and in case of $8 it should get all the factors

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  You are using the whole dataset 'df' as row index to subset some other `data_train`

Comment: Yes! originally df contains indexes and I want to pass them as row index in data_train, I know it sounds stupid but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: I posted a solution below.  May be that is what you wanted.  But, it is better to show a reproducible example for `data_train` and expected output

Comment: Have you tried the second solution below?

Comment: Can you also update the `data_train` as your new update is confusing.

Comment: um thanks I figured it out myself , thanks again :)

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I wasn't storing the values from lapply function below in df so I was getting index values mode instead of my attributes `Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux)); ux[tab == max(tab)]
}
result<-lapply(df,Mode)`  This is what I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to use the 'df' columns as row/column index to subset the `data_train`, then convert it to `matrix` and just subset the 'data_train'

```
data_train[as.matrix(df)]
```

Or if the columns in 'df' are the row index and want to subset the 5th column, then loop over the columns of 'df' and subset the 'data_train'

```
lapply(df, function(x) data_train[as.numeric(x), 5])
```

Comment: it gives this error Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @melissa I updated with another option in case that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thannks it worked can you please tell me how to get the mod of this list/dataframe I'm getting?

Comment: @melissa What do you mean by `mod`?  You could check `str(yourResult)`

Comment: sorry I meant mode